# Unity Google Street View

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a street view 360 viewer. Which should work on 2 screens.
One is a monitor and one is a oculus rift.
The first user will be sitting in front of the monitor and selecting street view images from a list / database.
The second user will wear the oculus rift and can see the street view images.

There is a plugin that can download panoramas from street view https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28512 , 
but this will only work in the unity editor.

Well here is the problem. I need to update this programm once in a while. So maybe there will be new images every week, the user should be able to select them. If they start the programm, there will be a screen saying that there is an update available. The programm should than download all new images and after that, they will be available for the users.
So I am wondering if it is possible to download panoramas from street view in runtime? Like there will be a database with all url's to the panoramas, the programm will check that database, download all new one and convert them to skybox oder 6-sided pictures.

Thanks.
I am using unity 5.4 and it should work on a PC

Answer (score 0):

You can download the images using the Google Street View API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=en

Example URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Please not that the images will be 400px * 600px, to get higher resolution you'll have to pay.

You'll have to make a different request for each camera angle (the max allowed FoV is 120, meaning you'll need three images to make the whole horizontal circle).

Honestly, I would do the whole image managing and updating thing server side. I would set up an interface in the browser where you can add new interest spots, then the server downloads the images and creates the cubemaps. The Unity client will just ask the server for a list of all the interesting places and once you chose one it will download the cubemap. Maybe it's because I have a web dev background, but to me it makes more sense than doing everything inside Unity.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. That does make sense to load and convert the images server side. But I don't have a web background, so I am not able to make a web interface for something like that :(

Do you know how expensive it will be for High Res images? I guess they are using some kind of "pay-per-viewed-image" pricing. So each time someone opens that images it will cost?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the pricing, but maybe this will help you: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/